# How to get all table columns as hash in rails from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code returns the `table-names` **How do I get the individual column names within the table?**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
 #=> ["products","listings"]
```

How do I get: `Products.< all columns >`

Comment: Did you try `Product.column_names`?

Comment: Yes and I get `#<NameError: uninitialized constant Products>`

Comment: Not `Products`. `Product`. :)

Comment: Yea i just saw my mistake. Thanks. Mark as answer --- I will accept.

Comment: Yeah, I'm following a codeshool tutorial. And I forgot about that convention. Thank you. I realized as I read back my second comment that I was calling the plural.

Comment: No worries. At the very start, it feels a little odd, but you quickly get used to Rails conventions on naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, the active record class of a table name is the singular form, and capitalized.

So to get the columns for the `products` table, you would use:

```
Product.column_names
```

This provides an array of all the column names for the table represented by the ActiveRecord object, `Product`.

Comment: There's also `Product.columns.map(&:name)` which is what `column_names` does internally.